# How do I automatically adjust subplot options for a matplotlib figure having a plot and a table?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270153/420385) shows how to manually tweak parameters with `subplots_adjust()` in order to avoid cutting-off a table that is located below a plot in a matplotlib figure.

My question is:  if the number of rows in the table is not known in advance, what is a sensible way of getting the needed dimensions in the figure, and automatically setting the values of `subplots_adjust()` to make the entire table and plot visible?

I am looking for something similar to `tight_layout()`, but which will work when there is a table present. `tight_layout()` seems to disregard tables in a figure -- or do I need to do something specifically in order to make `tight_layout()` work with tables?