# Adding an annotation box to a matplotlib contour/heat map plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I want generate a contour plot/heat map with a color bar and then add an annotation box.  This figure is ugly, but gets at what I want:

[image: example image]

`add_subplot()` is not enough.  If I try to put everything in the same subplot, the box gets covered up.  I can get around this by making it dragable and then futzing with the size of the image, but this is no good.  I am going to have to make several of these images, all of a standard size, and I can't fight with the size over and over again.

I tried `axes()` as well, putting the box in a separate axis. But that generates a new window for plotting that covers up most of my color bar.  I guess there would be ways to make the window completely transparent.  But when I get to that point, I think my approach must be completely wrong.

This doesn't seem like it should be so hard.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270153/matplotlib-table-gets-cropped/11270791#11270791) can be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Annotation box to contour map:

[image: much better graph]

Done like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import HBoxDivider
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_size as Size


def make_heights_equal(fig, rect, ax1, ax2, ax3, pad):
    # pad in inches

    h1, v1 = Size.AxesX(ax1), Size.AxesY(ax1)
    h2, v2 = Size.AxesX(ax2, 0.1), Size.AxesY(ax2)
    h3, v3 = Size.AxesX(ax3), Size.AxesY(ax3)

    pad_v = Size.Scaled(1)
    pad_h = Size.Fixed(pad)

    my_divider = HBoxDivider(fig, rect,
                             horizontal=[h1, pad_h, h2, pad_h, h3],
                             vertical=[v1, pad_v, v2, pad_v, v3])


    ax1.set_axes_locator(my_divider.new_locator(0))
    ax2.set_axes_locator(my_divider.new_locator(2))
    ax3.set_axes_locator(my_divider.new_locator(4))


# Make plot with vertical (default) colorbar
fig = plt.figure()
img_ax = fig.add_subplot(131)
bar_ax = fig.add_subplot(132)
ann_ax = fig.add_subplot(133)

data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)

im = img_ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm)

# Add colorbar, make sure to specify tick locations to match desired ticklabels
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=bar_ax, ticks=[-1, 0, 1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['< -1', '0', '> 1'])# vertically oriented colorbar

ann_ax.axis('off')

ann_ax.annotate("Hello, I'm an annotation", (0.5, 0.5),
                 xycoords="axes fraction", va="center", ha="center",
                 bbox=dict(boxstyle="round, pad=1", fc="w")) 

make_heights_equal(fig, 111, img_ax, bar_ax, ann_ax, 0.2)

plt.savefig("try.png")
```

Comment: Much obliged.  My boss will never go for that honkin' big colorbar, though.  Thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I know! was just putting down my first attempt. Here's a much better looking graph. Not very clean way of doing it but gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rather simple solution, using the `make_axes_locatable` function from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1`, as this makes the colorbar the same height as the image. Further it is very easy to set the placement, width and padding of the colorbar relative to the `Axes`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import randn

# Make plot with vertical (default) colorbar
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, aspect='equal')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, aspect='equal')
ax2.axis('off')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

# Specify placement, width and padding of colorbar
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="10%", pad=0.1)

data = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)

im = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.set_title('Title')

# Add colorbar, make sure to specify tick locations to match desired ticklabels
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, ticks=[-1, 0, 1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['< -1', '0', '> 1'])# vertically oriented colorbar

# Add text
boxtext = \
"""Text box
Second line
Third line"""

props = dict(boxstyle='round, pad=1', facecolor='white', edgecolor='black')
ax2.text(0.15, 0.85, boxtext, ha='left', va='top', transform=ax2.transAxes, bbox=props)

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(r'D:\image.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=150)
```

[image]

Comment: Much cleaner placement of the colorbar. Nice.

Comment: Much obliged, nordev.  brice got here first, so I'm accepting his.  But many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm going with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pickle

data  = np.clip(randn(250, 250), -1, 1)

fig3 = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig3.add_axes([.1,.1,.55,.8])
ax2 = fig3.add_axes([.7,.1,.05,.8])
ax3 = fig3.add_axes([.78,.1,.1,.8])
ax3.axis('off')

hm = ax1.pcolor(data, cmap=cm.coolwarm) 

plt.colorbar(hm,cax = ax2)

bbox_args = dict(boxstyle='square',facecolor='white')
ann = ax3.annotate('More info here', xy=(.2,.8),
              xytext=(.2,.8), transform=ax3.transAxes, bbox=bbox_args)

plt.show()
```

Result is:

[image: example plot from above code]

Not that this is better than the other answers provided (for which I am very grateful!) but I can understand it (!) and tweak it pretty easily.  I'm not going to select my own answer, because reading the others is what got me thinking along the lines I needed to make my own.  (Especially, did not know about axis('off') and was not thinking about putting the colorbar in its own axis object.  Did I mention I'm a noob?)  Anyway, if anyone wants a third alternative, here's this one.